# How to make '() to be nil?

Tags: clojure

How to make clojure to count `'()` as `nil`?

For example:
How to make something like

```
(if '() :true :false) 

;to be 

:false

;Or easier 

(my-fun/macro/namespace/... (if '() :true :false))

:false
```

And not just if. In every way.

```
(= nil '()) or (my-something (= nil '()))

true
```

And every code to be (= '() nil) save.

```
(something (+ 1 (if (= nil '()) 1 2)))

2
```

I was thinking about some kind of regural expression. Which will look on code and replace `'()` by `nil`, but there are some things like `(rest '(1))` and many others which are `'()` and I am not sure how to handle it.

I was told that macros allow you to build your own languages. I want to try it by changing clojure. So this is much about "How clojure works and how to change it?" than "I really need it to for my work."

Thank you for help.

Comment: One option is to downgrade to a sufficiently old version of Clojure. The empty sequence used to be nil, but this was changed: http://blog.n01se.net/blog-n01se-net-p-39.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you would like to change Clojure using the macros. Presently, as far as I know, this is not something you could do with the "regular" macro system (terminology fix anyone?). What you would really need (I *think*) is a reader macro. Things I have seen online ([here](http://www.infoq.com/interviews/hickey-clojure-reader), for example) seem to say that there exists something *like* reader macros in Clojure 1.4--but I have no familiarity with this because I really like using [clooj](https://github.com/arthuredelstein/clooj) as my IDE, and it currently is not using Clojure 1.4. Maybe somebody else has better info on this "extensible reader" magic.

Regardless, I don't really like the idea of changing the language in that way, and I think there is a potentially very good alternative: namely, the Clojure function [`not-empty`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/not-empty).

This function takes any collection and either returns that collection as is, or returns `nil` if that collection is empty. This means that anywhere you will want `()` to return `nil`, you should wrap it `not-empty`. This answer is very similar to mikera's answer above, except that you don't *have* to convert your collections to sequences (which can be nice).

Both using `seq` and `not-empty` are pretty silly in cases where you have a "hand-written" collection. After all, if you are writing it by hand (or rather, typing it manually), then you are going to know for sure whether or not it is empty. The cases in which this is useful is when you have an expression or a symbol that returns a collection, and you do not know whether the returned collection will be empty or not.

Example:

```
=> (if-let [c (not-empty (take (rand-int 5) [:a :b :c :d]))]
     (println c)
     (println "Twas empty"))
;//80% of the time, this will print some non-empty sub-list of [:a :b :c :d]
;//The other 20% of the time, this will return...
Twas empty
=> nil
```

Comment: I don't think reader macros are suited for this task. In clojure they are very limited, compared to other lisp dialects.

Answer (score 12):

`'()` just isn't the same thing as `nil` - why would you want it do be?

What you might be looking for though is the `seq` function, which returns nil if given an empty collection:

```
(seq [1 2 3])
=> (1 2 3)

(seq [])
=> nil

(seq '())
=> nil
```

`seq` is therefore often used to test for "emptiness", with idioms like:

```
(if (seq coll)
  (do-something-with coll)
  (get-empty-result))
```

Comment: To have Common Lisp like notation with easy acces to java libraries. 

I, may be, posted wrong exaples. I also want to (+ 1 (if (= nil '()) 1 2)) to be 2. (seq (+ 1 (if (= nil '()) 1 2))) do not help.

Comment: The Clojure approach is I think better for use with Java libraries (which often return nil/null to mean "no result found"). I think you may be best just embracing the Clojure approach. '() doesn't have any special meaning in Clojure or Java. Use nil/null instead in situations where you might have used '() in CL.

Comment: I was wanted to keep that question simple. But maybe it was mistake. I believe that it will be easy to write short (common-lisp- interpreter ...) that allows runs Common Lisp or hybrid code on Clojure. This is just small part of it. I understand your answer and I am  thankful for it. But in other hand it is like: a:"How I can do something?" b:"You do not want to do that." I am sorry but this do not satisfy me. (I am really thankful for your effort.)

Comment: @mikera you should capture the return value of `seq` with an `if-let`.

Answer (score 1):

What about `empty?` ? It's the most expressive.

```
(if (empty? '())
  :true
  :false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override macros and functions. For instance:

```
(defn classic-lisp [arg]
  (if (seq? arg) (seq arg) arg))

(defn = [& args]
  (apply clojure.core/= (map classic-lisp args)))

(defmacro when [cond & args] 
  `(when (classic-lisp ~cond) ~@args))
```

Unfortunately, you can't override if, as it is a special form and not a macro. You will have to wrap your code with another macro.

Let's make an if* macro to be an if with common-lisp behavior:

```
(defmacro if* [cond & args]
    `(if (classic-lisp ~cond) ~@args)
```

With this, we can replace all ifs with if*s:

```
(use 'clojure.walk)
(defn replace-ifs [code]
  (postwalk-replace '{if if*} (macroexpand-all code)))
(defmacro clojure-the-old-way [& body]
  `(do ~@(map replace-ifs body)))
```

Now:

```
=> (clojure-the-old-way (if '() :true :false) )
:false
```

You should be able to load files and replace ifs in them too:

```
(defn read-clj-file [filename]
  ;; loads list of clojure expressions from file *filename*
  (read-string (str "(" (slurp filename)  ")"))) 

(defn load-clj-file-the-old-way [filename]
  (doseq [line (replace-ifs (read-clj-file filename))] (eval line))
```

Note that I didn't test the code to load files and it might be incompatible with leiningen or namespaces. I believe it should work with overriden = though.